# Custom confirm button with promise jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

i'm trying to create a custom confirm pop up in jquery, i made a function that shows the custom alert when requested with inside a text and two buttons: ok, cancel.:

```
function showprompt(content){
   $("#confirm").css("display","block");
   $("#msg").text(content); 
}
```

The problem is that how i can wait until the button clicked and get back the result, if ok so return true? i was thinking that i need to use promise and defer. How i can do?

I don't like to use precreated confirm buttons with plugins JQuery UI - Dialog

Comment: can use a promise., custom event or a callback. Either way will need another event handler on a button in your custom prompt UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A promise is a great idea for this type of functionality (they're not only for async!). Let's say you have two buttons inside of `#confirm` are called `#ok` and `#cancel`.

This is how it would look:

```
function showprompt(content) {
   var dfd = $.Deferred();

   $('#confirm').css('display','block')
   $('#msg').text(content);

   $('#confirm')
     //turn off any events that were bound to the buttons last 
     //time you called showprompt()
     .off('click.prompt') 

      //resolve the deferred
     .on('click.prompt','#ok',function() { dfd.resolve(); }) 

      //reject the deferred
     .on('click.prompt','#cancel',function() { dfd.reject(); });

   //return a the deferred's promise
   return dfd.promise();
}
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
showprompt(content).then(
   function() { alert('You clicked ok'); }, //promise resolved
   function() { alert('You clicked cancel'); }, //promise rejected
);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much @Adam you saved me, i tried for hours and hours, you did that in only few seconds :)

Comment: `dfd.resolve` and `dfd.reject` are "detachable", allowing you to write `.on('click.prompt', '#ok', dfd.resolve)` and `.on('click.prompt', '#cancel', dfd.reject)`
Also the dialog is best hidden with an `.always()` chained to the Deferred. 
https://jsfiddle.net/cLo6pus3/

Comment: I find another problem is that how i can get back the true or false status inside showprompt otherwise the alert()?

Comment: what true/false status?

Comment: @JaromandaX i tried that line console.log(showprompt("test!").then(function(){ return true;},function(){return false;})); but it doesn't want to work

Comment: @AbdeluadudHakimi - that doesn't work because promises do not make asynchronous code synchronous

Comment: @JaromandaX mmm, and what is the best solution to return that value? the confirm prompt returns the true status to know if the ok button was clicked..

Comment: @AbdeluadudHakimi - you can't wrap `console.log` around your `showprompt` call - you have to put the `console.log` inside your callbacks that are inside your `then` - the ones that return true or false.

Comment: and the best way to get it returned? the console log it's just for trying, if i want that if(the button clicked it's ok and return true) then continue? , sorry for all that questions, i had some problems to understand the promise function

Comment: @AbdeluadudHakimi - promises are not used to `return` values, they are used to execute callbacks based on values that will be returned at some point in the future. You cannot return true or false directly from `showprompt` if it returns a promise, you HAVE to do your work inside the callbacks. `showprompt().then(function() { console.log('you clicked ok'); });`

Comment: ok, now i understand thank you so much @Adam and thanks to everyone that helped me!